# Ajax Submission from ckeditor4 form produces Server Error 510 on specific character input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I have ckeditor in use for a cms. It is working fairly well in general. However, i stumbled over a problem which happens in rare cases. With some special strings, the submission will fail and produces a Error 510.
Basically it is a form with a textarea field, which is transformed to an ckeditor field. On submit, the form is serialized and submitted via ajax to an script.
The string which causes the problem is

```
üls z
```

A working example can b found here: 
http://web1068.login-4.loginserver.ch/ckeditor/

Clicking on the word "send" will produce the error which can be seen in the console. Removing part of the string in the textarea will make it work. The Problem does not happen when using a plain texarea field.

The HTML Code is:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery_min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
            function() {
                $('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor();
                $(".button").click(function(){
                    $(".result").html('');
                    var data=$("form").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",url: 'test_ckeditor2.php',
                        data: data,
                        dataType:'html',
                        beforeSend: function() {},
                        complete: function() {}, 
                        success: function(res){
                            $(".result").html(res);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea class="ckeditor" name="xyz">üls z</textarea>
            <div class="button">Send</div>
        </form>
            <div class="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Script called is just returning the string "Form submitted" + the string submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was caused by Security Settings on the Server side and solved by the Provider.